# Find same elements in a list, and then change these elemens to tuple (f.e. 2 to (2,1))

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Find same elements in list, and then change these elements to tuple (f.e. 2 to (2, 1)), adding a count to repeated elements.

So I have this list:

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

I want to get:

```
a = [(1, 1), (2, 1), 4, 3, (2, 2), (1, 2)]
```

where the second element is a counter (starting at 1), so the second `1` number is replaced with `(1, 2)`. A third would become `(1, 3)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Moreover, I can't quite see how the input list leads to the output given. Why  `(2, 1)` and `(1, 2)`, for example?

Comment: Is the second value in the tuple a counter perhaps, starting at 1? Why not also add such a count `4` and `3`, even though they'd only go up to `1`?

Comment: Thank you! idea i want to replace same elemets in the list to tuple, because after I want to zip this with other list to dict, and as you know Python doesnt support same key in dict, so I'm trying to make it like this.

1 -> (1,1) if its first 1

Comment: In which case adding `(4, 1)` instead of `4` is fine, right?

Comment: No, 4 is not repeated.

Comment: But why not collect all the values into lists? So `{1: [first, second], 2: [first, second], 3: [first]}`? Then you can still use the same values as keys and reference *all* values for those keys.

Comment: Yes, I understood that `4` is not repeated. But now you are creating *inconsistent keys*. You give your code a lot more work later on trying to figure out if a key is a tuple or just an integer. You'll have a much easier time being *consistent*.

Comment: it a good idea, thank you! I will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just add a count you could keep a set of [`itertools.count` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) in a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict

counters = defaultdict(lambda: count(1))

result = [(n, next(counters[n])) for n in inputlist]
```

but this would add counts to *all* elements in your list:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> counters = defaultdict(lambda: count(1))
>>> inputlist = [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> [(n, next(counters[n])) for n in inputlist]
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2)]
```

This keeps your output consistent and avoids having to later test if one of these elements is an integer or a tuple.

If you **have** to produce tuples only for repeated elements, you'll have to do two steps; create a count with [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) then use the same counting trick as above but only for those elements whose total count is greater than 1:

```
from itertools import count
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

counters = defaultdict(lambda: count(1))
tally = Counter(inputlist)

result = [(n, next(counters[n])) if tally[n] > 1 else n for n in inputlist]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counters = defaultdict(lambda: count(1))
>>> tally = Counter(inputlist)
>>> [(n, next(counters[n])) if tally[n] > 1 else n for n in inputlist]
[(1, 1), (2, 1), 4, 3, (2, 2), (1, 2)]
```

However, if you are trying to produce 'unique' keys for a dictionary, consider grouping the *values* instead, so instead of:

```
{(1, 1): foo, (1, 2): bar}
```

produce lists or sets:

```
{1: [foo, bar]}
{1: {foo, bar}}
```

You can do so with a `defaultdict` too:

```
result = defaultdict(set)
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    result[key].add(value)
```

to produce a set per key, or use `defauldict(list)` and `result[key].append(value)` to produce a list.

Comment: Did not understand the last part about dictionary, what do you suggest?

Comment: @VadimBorisov: added a suggestion.